# Excel - Finding a string in another workbook with formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have ISBN-13 numbers in a column. I want to search and find each of them in another workbook with a formula and to write 1 if there is a match and 0 if there is no match in another column next to ISBN-13 numbers.

This is what I tried:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(AG2,'[RECEIVING.xlsx]1'!$B:$E,0)),1,0)
```

AG column is where ISBN-13 numbers are located.

But the result that I got is 0 in every cell in that column. But there should be matches. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try using MATCH on a single column, you are using it on columns B to E, select only the one that holds your ISBN-13 numbers

Comment: You are using `MATCH()` on a range of columns `B:E`. That's not a valid range. Try `=SUMPRODUCT(--('[RECEIVING.xlsx]1'!$B:$E=AG2))` or something like that.

Comment: Or if matches can be in any of the four columns to B, C, D, and E separately - i.e. use your existing formula four time and add together the results.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get it how do I do that? @zsalya